# Can't stop attack on nginx server

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, security, firewall, ddos

I'm currently struggling with my Digitalocean droplet (Ubuntu 22.10) which is under some sort of attack (maybe DDOS). The server hosts a containerized application that runs on nginx.

Every time I access the droplet console I can see hundreds of lines like the following:

```
nginx_1       | 2024/02/06 10:14:20 [error] 8#8: *1425 access forbidden by rule, client: 94.130.56.244, server: **********, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/EQAFJzQBOu70iOKYwkrcDyvxQFuf8QgkeOMFyf5_LJs HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mesoskinline24.fr"
```

As you can see, there is no real security issue because I have inserted a rule that denies access to that particular IP. I also disabled access logs to avoid memory leaks. Even though it's no longer a security issue, it's very annoying to see the server console flooded with lines like the one I just showed.

Countermeasures attempted so far:

- Using ufw to block the access to the droplet `sudo ufw deny from 94.130.56.244` + `sudo ufw reload`, not working.
- Using IPTABLE directly with the command: `iptables -A INPUT -s 94.130.56.244 -j DROP`, not working.
- Tried to prevent nginx route `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` from logging in console but I didn't really found a way to do so.

Thank you in advance for helping out!

Comment: Congratulations! You're connected to the Internet. This is the kind of stuff that *will* show up as long as you're connected to the Internet. You may use a service such as fail2ban to automatically parse logs for offenders, or you may ignore it.

Comment: If it is always coming from the same IP address (as your attempts to block a specific address imply) then it is, by definition, not a DDoS attack. Most likely it is not an attack at all, but connection attempts to a service that ran on a previous owner of the IP address, from some client still running with outdated information.

Comment: Can't you block it on the droplet firewall https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/firewalls/how-to/view-rules-for-droplet/

Comment: @Turdie thank you for the comment! Unfortunately, as I understood, Digitalocean firewall works with a whitelist mechanism so I can't stop a single IP. Correct me if i'm wrong because your suggestion was the very first thing coming in my mind when facing the problem for the first time. :)

Comment: You can create a rule to allow all traffic on http and then a rule to block a certain ip

Comment: Congratulations! @vidarlo you’ve now gained the Mr. Obvious gold medal :) I know the dynamics of the internet thank you! My question was about preventing the request to reach the nginx server. I will take in consideration fail2ban as last option. Thank you

Comment: Sorry you’re right, drop a D because this is not a distributed attack! Anyway in an nginx standard configuration this leads to a memory leak due to the huge amount of logs stored. For this reason I thought it might have been a DOS. Anyway thank you for the suggestion but I would like to understand how to block the request at droplet level! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could install fail2ban with a nginx jail, which automatically scans the logfiles and blocks certain traffic

After you have installed fail2ban, you can create a jail in /etc/fail2ban/jail.d/nginx.conf (for example)

In that file you put this

```
[nginx-http-auth]
enabled = true
mode = normal
port    = http,https
logpath = %(nginx_error_log)s
```

You can also put this in there, but for that you need to *To use 'nginx-limit-req' jail you should have `ngx_http_limit_req_module` and define `limit_req` and `limit_req_zone` as described in nginx documentation*

```
[nginx-limit-req]
enabled = true 
port    = http,https
logpath = %(nginx_error_log)s
```

This one is very useful in cases of excessive traffic, including DDoS attacks

---

Here is an PowerShell script to block a certain ip in a droplet firewall

```
# Set your DigitalOcean API token
$token = "YOUR_DIGITALOCEAN_API_TOKEN"

# Set the ID of the firewall you want to modify
$firewallId = "YOUR_FIREWALL_ID"

# Set the IP address you want to block
$ipToBlock = "IP_ADDRESS_TO_BLOCK"

# Define the API endpoint URL
$endpoint = "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/firewalls/$firewallId"

# Define the JSON payload to add a new inbound rule blocking the specified IP address
$jsonPayload = @{
    inbound_rules = @(
        @{
            protocol = "tcp"
            ports = ""
            sources = @{
                addresses = @($ipToBlock)
            }
        }
    )
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Make the API request to update the firewall
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $endpoint -Method Put -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} -ContentType "application/json" -Body $jsonPayload

# Check if the request was successful
if ($response) {
    Write-Host "IP address $ipToBlock has been blocked in the firewall."
} else {
    Write-Host "Failed to block IP address $ipToBlock in the firewall."
}
```

---

If you don't want it to reach the nginx server, I came across a docker-waf which you can put in front of your webserver, and use Modsecurity to block malicious traffic together with the owasp modsecurity crs rules
https://github.com/theonemule/docker-waf

There is also a Dos protection in the OWASP Modsecurity CRS.

Optional DoS protection against clients making requests too quickly.

```
#
# When a client is making more than 100 requests (excluding static files) within
# 60 seconds, this is considered a 'burst'. After two bursts, the client is
# blocked for 600 seconds.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @Turdie. As I mentioned in the comments below the question, I would like to figure out how to prevent the unwanted request to reach the nginx server in the first place... You mentioned the possibility to add a rule which blocks a specific IP in the droplet's firewall configuration. Unfortunately, after a few researches I did't figure out how to create it. Can you please suggest where I can learn how to do so or, if you already know the solution, explain it to me?

Comment: I came across another solution today, may I suggest that to you? For the droplet firewall, I will add a PowerShell script to do that to mu answer

Comment: I'm not so fund on blocking just one ip, because a threat actor will notice that and just use another ip. A smart threat actor has a bot or something like that and we blocked just use another ip out of a pool of ips